# Polynomial rings not useful when $R$ is a field?

Tags: ring-theory

When $R$ is a field then surely we end up for no use for polynomial rings as $R[x]=R$? As you can prove that:

> Suppose that $R$ is an integral domain. Then $(R[x])^{\times}=R^{\times}$

This should mean that if $R$ is a field i.e. everything is a unit but $0_R$ then every polynomial will have degree zero apart from the zero polynomial? Am I missing something?

Comment: Oh, no: it is not true *ever* that $\;R=R[x]\;,\;\;R$ a field...never!

Comment: Oh I see what I have done wrong... I've said $R$ field means $R^{\times}=R$ without $0_R=R[x]$ which it should be equal to $(R[x])^{\times}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are definitely missing something.

$\mathbb{R}[x]$ certainly isn't the same as $\mathbb{R}$. Say the polynomial $x^2 + 1$ would correspond to the real number $u$. What polynomial would then correspond to $u^{-1}$? There is no polynomial $q$ in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ with $q\cdot (x^2 + 1) = 1$...

The units in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ are the polynomials $(\neq 0)$ which only have a constant term. That's only a tiny part of the whole ring $\mathbb{R}[x]$.

Comment: Yes thank you just realised, god now I feel stupid... :/